# Regex condition and extract

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I'm parsing a file in bash, and I need to test if the current line is like this AND extract what's after "interface" :

> interface EthernetXXXX/YYY

or

> interface port-channelZZZZZ

where X, Y or Z is a number

Text sample :

```
 channel-group 105 mode active
   no shutdown

 interface Ethernet4/20
   description *** SW1-DT-A05-DC7 -> e1/37 ***
   switchport
   switchport mode trunk
   switchport trunk native vlan 201
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-394,396-1609
```

For example :

```
$REGEX = "^interface (REGEX)"
if [[ $line =~ $REGEX ]];
then
    ifname = $XXX #the extracted part from the regex, i.e Ethernet4/20
fi
```

Example :

```
#!/bin/bash

filename = $1
vlan = $2

while read line; do
  echo $line
  $REGEX = "^interface (.*)"
  $REGEX_VLAN = "switchport.*$vlan.*"
  if [[ $line =~ $REGEX ]];
  then
      ifname = $XXX #the extraxted part from the regex
  else
    if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_VLAN ]];
    then
      echo "Interface $ifname contain the vlan $vlan"
  fi
done <$filename
```

Do you know how to do this, if possible all in the if-statement ?

Comment: Yeah just write the regex.

Comment: Post the expected output

Comment: I'm not sure that bash accept space on both sides of the equal, and '$' at the beginning of variable name at its initialisation, no ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I've made so newbie error, it was a draft :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about used `grep` and `sed` ?

```
grep interface test_sample | sed 's@interface\(.*\)@\1@'
```

`grep` will search line with interface, and `sed` will extract part after interface. You can adjust `sed` regex to perfectly fit with your need

To use extract part, you can use a `for` loop :

```
for extract_part in $(grep interface test_sample | sed 's@interface\(.*\)@\1@')
do
  # you can do what you want with extract part
  echo $extract_part
done
```

Another solution, without call to external process :

```
while read -r line
do
  if [[ $line =~ "interface "(.*) ]]
  then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  fi
done < "./test_sample"
```

Comment: Because I need to do more after, in my parsing loop.
And there is a lot of interface XXXX, and I need to see each one

Comment: or use the 'match a line' feature of `sed` and skip the `grep`, i.e. `sed '/interface/{s@inteface\(.*\)@\1@;}'` . Good luck to all.

Comment: Or just skip calling external processes since bash can easily parse this.

Comment: @shellter, I try your proposition, but tell me if I wrong but sed 'match a line' feature don't allow to extract and obtain within for loop body only line with "interface"

Comment: @123, I edit my answer. was that what you were thinking ?

Comment: @romariccrailox Not really, you can use regex to match in the `if`, and then use `BASH_REMATCH` to display the matches

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is, i need to parse the entire part because I need to check some other information other than the interface line. I've updated my first post with the code example

Comment: @123 so use `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` with `"interface "(.*)` regex ? So in Rian post, `$XXX` should be replace with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` ?

Comment: Thanks guys, that what I was looking for : ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you.

Here's the "final" code about my question :

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
vlan=$2

while read line; do
  #echo $line
  REGEX="^interface (.*)"
  REGEX_VLAN="switchport.*$vlan.*"
  if [[ $line =~ $REGEX ]];
  then
      ifname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} #the extracted part from the regex
  else
    if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_VLAN ]];
    then
      echo "Interface $ifname contain the vlan $vlan"
    fi
  fi
done <$filename
```